# Accessing an XML file with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, object

Trying to read values from an XML file.

```xml
<Keyword id="Profanity List">
<Group matchStyle="word">
<Term caseSensitive="false">Trigger Profanity</Term>
<Term caseSensitive="false">TriggerProfanity</Term>
</Group>
</Keyword>
```

The following

```bsh
foreach ($term in $XmlDocument.RulePackage.Rules.Keyword.Group.Term) {
    $temp = $term | select '#text'
    $temp
}
```

displays

```
#text
-----
Trigger Profanity
TriggerProfanity
```

If I write to a string

```bsh
$xmldata2 += $temp
$xmldata2
```

I get

```xml
<Term>@{#text=TriggerProfanity}</Term>
<Term>@{#text=Trigger Profanity}</Term>
```

What I'm trying to write from the original file is

```xml
<Term>TriggerProfanity</Term>
<Term>Trigger Profanity</Term>
```

Clearly I'm writing the object rather than the string value, any idea how I access the value rather than the object?

Comment: how you imported the xml file?

Comment: [xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -path $xmloutfile

Comment: You need to expand the `#text` property: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty '#text'`

Comment: Perfect, that was where I was going wrong, thanks.